# Tesseract, openCV, python: how to get bounding box for a sentence or same line of text?

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I would like to do some text recognition on an image. I can recognise the text and the corresponding bounding box but only word by word, I would like to do the same thing on the same line of text. On my code below, I noticed that when I display my bounding box coordinates, when words are on the same line, the values of b['top'] are similar. I don't know if I can use this but I would like to have one bounding box per line of text and the associated sentence.

below the code i made :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import cv2 
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('./images/page_2.jpg') # load img

img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  #transform colored img to grayscale

plt.imshow(img)

boxes = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, output_type=Output.DICT) #transform image to dict

boxes = pd.DataFrame(boxes) #dict to dataframe
boxes['text'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True) #replace empty values by NaN
boxes= boxes.dropna(subset = ['text']) #delete rows with NaN 

print(boxes)

for index, b in boxes.iterrows():
    (x,y,w,h) = b['left'],b['top'],b['width'],b['height']
    print((x,y,w,h), b['text'])
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(w+x,h+y), (0,0,255),1)
    
cv2.imshow('result',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

output of "boxes" dict :

```
     level  page_num  block_num  par_num  line_num  word_num  left  top  \
4        5         1          1        1         1         1    32   24   
5        5         1          1        1         1         2   100   24   
6        5         1          1        1         1         3   191   28   
7        5         1          1        1         1         4   227   28   
8        5         1          1        1         1         5   257   24   
..     ...       ...        ...      ...       ...       ...   ...  ...   
154      5         1          1       11         1         7   261  457   
155      5         1          1       11         1         8   320  461   
156      5         1          1       11         1         9   351  457   
157      5         1          1       11         1        10   376  457   
158      5         1          1       11         1        11   468  457   

     width  height       conf       text  
4       60      17  93.283920     Maitre  
5       82      19  93.204414   corbeau,  
6       29      13  96.932060        sur  
7       22      12  96.932060         un  
8       50      17  93.306122      arbre  
..     ...     ...        ...        ...  
154     51      21  79.999794      qu'on  
155     23      13  90.411606         ne  
156     18      21  21.623993        I'y  
157     85      21  90.583260  prendrait  
158     44      21  96.933327      plus.
```

output of (x,y,w,h) and b['text'] (bounding box with is text) :

```
(32, 24, 60, 17) Maitre
(100, 24, 82, 19) corbeau,
(191, 28, 29, 13) sur
(227, 28, 22, 12) un
(257, 24, 50, 17) arbre
(315, 24, 70, 21) perché,
(79, 49, 58, 17) Tenait
(144, 53, 23, 13) en
(174, 53, 34, 13) son
(216, 50, 33, 16) bec
(257, 53, 22, 13) un
(287, 49, 84, 22) fromage.
(32, 75, 60, 17) Maitre
(100, 75, 61, 17) renard
(169, 79, 31, 17) par
(206, 75, 64, 17) I'odeur
(277, 75, 68, 17) alléché
(353, 88, 3, 6) ,
(81, 101, 27, 16) Lui
(115, 101, 28, 16) tint
(151, 100, 11, 17) 4
(169, 104, 34, 17) peu
(211, 100, 42, 21) prés
(260, 104, 21, 13) ce
(289, 101, 76, 20) langage
(374, 105, 3, 12) :
(81, 126, 31, 16) «Et
(119, 126, 72, 21) bonjour
(199, 126, 88, 17) Monsieur
(294, 126, 22, 16) du
(324, 125, 87, 18) Corbeau.
(31, 151, 40, 17) Que
(78, 155, 46, 13) vous
(131, 151, 40, 17) 6tes
(177, 151, 32, 21) joli!
(217, 155, 35, 17) que
(260, 155, 44, 13) vous
(312, 155, 29, 13) me
(348, 151, 80, 17) semblez
(436, 151, 52, 17) beau!
(81, 176, 47, 18) Sans
(136, 177, 63, 19) mentir,
(207, 177, 15, 17) si
(229, 178, 48, 16) votre
(284, 181, 72, 17) ramage
(81, 202, 25, 17) Se
(114, 204, 79, 19) rapporte
(200, 202, 11, 17) a
(218, 204, 48, 15) votre
(273, 203, 87, 20) plumage,
(31, 228, 48, 17) Vous
(86, 227, 40, 18) étes
(134, 228, 15, 16) le
(157, 227, 63, 21) phénix
(227, 228, 34, 17) des
(269, 227, 51, 18) hétes
(327, 228, 23, 16) de
(358, 232, 33, 13) ces
(398, 228, 49, 17) bois»
(31, 253, 53, 17) Aces
(92, 255, 45, 15) mots
(145, 253, 15, 17) le
(167, 253, 78, 17) corbeau
(253, 257, 22, 13) ne
(283, 257, 22, 13) se
(312, 255, 40, 15) sent
(360, 257, 33, 17) pas
(400, 253, 23, 17) de
(429, 253, 40, 21) joie;
(81, 279, 19, 16) Et
(107, 283, 43, 16) pour
(157, 280, 74, 16) montrer
(238, 283, 22, 13) sa
(267, 279, 45, 16) belle
(319, 279, 43, 19) voix,
(33, 304, 8, 16) ll
(49, 308, 53, 13) ouvre
(110, 308, 22, 13) un
(140, 304, 47, 21) large
(195, 304, 33, 17) bec
(236, 304, 54, 17) laisse
(297, 305, 67, 16) tomber
(371, 308, 22, 13) sa
(400, 304, 53, 21) proie.
(32, 330, 23, 17) Le
(63, 330, 60, 16) renard
(131, 330, 38, 17) s'en
(177, 330, 48, 17) saisit
(232, 331, 17, 15) et
(256, 330, 28, 16) dit:
(291, 330, 49, 16) "Mon
(348, 330, 35, 16) bon
(391, 330, 92, 19) Monsieur,
(103, 355, 92, 21) Apprenez
(202, 359, 36, 17) que
(245, 356, 35, 16) tout
(287, 355, 67, 17) flatteur
(31, 381, 25, 16) Vit
(63, 385, 34, 12) aux
(104, 381, 71, 20) dépens
(181, 381, 24, 16) de
(212, 381, 43, 16) celui
(262, 381, 28, 20) qui
(298, 380, 79, 17) l'écoute:
(32, 406, 50, 17) Cette
(90, 406, 50, 21) lecon
(148, 407, 40, 16) vaut
(195, 406, 40, 17) bien
(243, 410, 22, 13) un
(273, 406, 79, 21) fromage
(359, 410, 45, 13) sans
(411, 406, 67, 17) doute."
(81, 432, 22, 16) Le
(110, 432, 77, 16) corbeau
(195, 432, 76, 16) honteux
(279, 433, 17, 15) et
(303, 432, 63, 16) confus
(31, 457, 42, 17) Jura
(81, 457, 44, 17) mais
(133, 461, 22, 13) un
(163, 461, 34, 17) peu
(205, 457, 36, 17) tard
(250, 470, 3, 6) ,
(261, 457, 51, 21) qu'on
(320, 461, 23, 13) ne
(351, 457, 18, 21) I'y
(376, 457, 85, 21) prendrait
(468, 457, 44, 21) plus.
```

image result:

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCgt9.png)

Comment: Better post the text outputs as text rather than images.

Comment: I don't understand your comment sorry, where in the code ?

Comment: I mean not _the code_, but the question post. Images of text (in this case the _dict_ and the _box with text_) hinder people to copy the data in order to look for a solution to your problem. Even better than the posted text, post the output of `boxes.to_dict()`.

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that when I display my bounding box coordinates, when words are on the same line, the values of b['top'] are similar. I don't know if I can use this but I would like to have one bounding box per line of text and the associated sentence.

You can use this exactly. This generates the lines by aggregating the vertically overlapping boxes:

```
def lineup(boxes):
    linebox = None
    for _, box in boxes.iterrows():
        if linebox is None: linebox = box           # first line begins
        elif box.top <= linebox.top+linebox.height: # box in same line
            linebox.top = min(linebox.top, box.top)
            linebox.width = box.left+box.width-linebox.left
            linebox.heigth = max(linebox.top+linebox.height, box.top+box.height)-linebox.top
            linebox.text += ' '+box.text
        else:                                       # box in new line
            yield linebox
            linebox = box                           # new line begins
    yield linebox                                   # return last line

lineboxes = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lineup(boxes))
```